# Adding jitter or transparency to points in Highcharter scatter plot in R

Tags: r, highcharts

I am figuring out how to put jitter parameters or add some transparency to a scatter plot in R using the Highcharter library. I find most of the code is related to Javascript. But I am looking for additional parameters to be put in so that my points are not overplotted.

[image]

Here is the code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

clist %>%
  hchart("scatter", hcaes(x = completion_rate, y = synergy_scores, group = course_code)) %>% 
           hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Completion rate")) %>%
          hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Synergy score")) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat ="<b> Synergy score: </b> {point.y} <br>") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Courses with positive and negative Synergy scores")
```

Data: [here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/y1i9wmx2sz8cefz/courselist_completion_rates.csv?dl=0)

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you could do is use `states` which means that when you highlight one point, the other points `opacity` will be lower. Here is code:

```
library(highcharter)
library(tidyverse)

clist %>%
  hchart("scatter", hcaes(x = completion_rate, y = synergy_scores, group = course_code)) %>% 
  hc_xAxis(title = list(text = "Completion rate")) %>%
  hc_yAxis(title = list(text = "Synergy score")) %>% 
  hc_tooltip(pointFormat ="<b> Synergy score: </b> {point.y} <br>") %>% 
  hc_title(text = "Courses with positive and negative Synergy scores") %>%
  hc_plotOptions(series = list(states = list(inactive = list(opacity = 0.5))))
```

Output:

[image]

What you can see is that the other points have lower transparency than the one that is highlighted.